# What are some examples of famous people in history who made big mistakes that they learnt from and this then led them to succeed?

Tags: famous-people

I’m a primary school teacher in an inner London school in England. I’ve been talking with my class about how important it is to make mistakes and how we can learn from our mistakes to reach our goal. As part if this, the children have asked me for examples of famous people in history who made mistakes that helped them to get things right/succeed.

I’ve been looking online to find something and so far I can find a lot of great quotes about not being afraid to make mistakes but not a lot of examples of people/groups who made mistakes that they learnt from to get to their end goal. I’ve found Thomas Edison with the lightbulb and how it took him 1000 attempts and each attempt brought him closer.

Can you think of anyone else that I could use as an example that would be exciting/relevant for young children. Ideally I want to put together as many examples as possible of famous people in History who got things wrong but then learnt from those mistakes and it helped them to succeed. Are there any leaders who made mistakes to lose a battle but then learnt from those mistakes which then led to them winning the war? I am particularly keen to get some good diversity in there so if you know of any good examples of women and/or people of colour as well that would be super helpful.

Response to questions for clarification:
Thanks for your advice below that is already helpful and thanks for your patience with me figuring out the best way to respond.

Mark, I definitely understand what you were saying about the example anti-pattern. I guess rather than looking for a definitive answer of just one example I am more looking for a variety of examples which may offer differing qualities/insights (I am acutely aware how subjective a question it is that I am asking). The main things for me are:

Is it historically accurate and provable through historical evidence as opposed to conjecture/here-say.
There is a specific example of a particular mistake they made rather than a generalised notion of them making mistakes over time.
Will it be an example from world history that a child of 5-7yrs old can access and there is a clear connection between the mistake they made and learnt from and the eventual success it led to. An ideal example would be something like an ancient historical leader who made a strategic error that led to them losing a battle but they learnt their lesson and so next time did something different that led to them winning.
Sorry to ask such a subjective question. I guess what I’m hoping is that although it may be personal opinion for why certain famous figures would make good examples of learning from their own mistakes, hopefully there would be enough general agreement for those people being acceptable that I would feel comfortable using them.

Lars- if you think this is not the right place to ask such an open ended question I totally respect that and can look to try on a more appropriate forum. Thanks for the advice

Thanks

Matt

Comment: Hitler first tried to grab power by force (in 1923). This did not work and landed him in prison. The next time he tried to take power he followed an outwardly legal process and took care to have parts of the old elites (Hindenburg, Papen) on his side.

Comment: On the one hand, this question seems hopelessly broad. On the other hand, its aim is worthy. I would suggest that a sort of solution to the issue of selecting an authoritative answer would be for someone to start a Community Wiki answer to which others can add examples for Matt to consider using in his class.

Comment: This reminds me that there used to be a show on US TV called [Biography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biography_(TV_program)), and it seemed like *every* story had that kind of arc in it. I don't know if they were crowbarring everyone's personal stories into that format because it worked for them as producers, or if it really just is that universal. But I see that there's a "Biography for Kids" in there, and I'd bet those are available to schools (although perhaps in US screen dimensions).

Answer (score 3):

Community wiki answer; please add examples.

**From the US**

- [Abraham Lincoln](http://www.abrahamlincolnonline.org/lincoln/education/failures.htm).
- [Alexander Hamilton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Hamilton)'s mistake may not be appropriate for primary school children.
- [George Washington](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Washington)'s military career is an unrelenting series of failures that culminated in success & trust.
- The [Wright brothers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_brothers) learnt not only from [their own failures but also the failures of others](https://www.intellectualventures.com/buzz/insights/failing-for-success-the-wright-brothers/).
- [Walt Disney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walt_Disney#Early_career:_1920%E2%80%931928)'s first company went bankrupt.

**From the British Isles**

- [Alfred](https://www.historic-uk.com/HistoryUK/HistoryofEngland/King-Alfred-the-Cakes/)
- [Henry II and Beckett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_II_of_England)
- [Isembard Kingdom Brunel](https://www.historyextra.com/period/victorian/brunel-the-flawed-genius/)'s record was not stellar, but was persistent.
- [Winston Churchill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winston_Churchill) has failed as a politician time after time, but succeeded when it really counted, during the 2nd World War. Churchill's quote "Success consists of going from failure to failure without loss of enthusiasm." might be useful.
- [Richard Branson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Branson) has had quite a few failures along the way to his billions.

**From Germany**

- [Paul Ehrlich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Ehrlich#Magic_bullet)'s search for a [Magic bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_bullet_(medicine)) was abandoned for a while after initial failures with his experiments.

**From Ancient Rome**

- [Julius Caesar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julius_Caesar). The mistakes made during the set back at the [Battle of Gergovia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Gergovia) were not repeated later the same year at the [Battle of Alesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Alesia).

Comment: Which Henry II?  If the English one, what mistakes did he learn from?  He was a successful king except for his last year or two, which were dreadful.

Comment: I would add Churchill himself to this list: He failed as a politician time after time, until when it really counted, during WWII.

Comment: @MoisheKohan - it is community wiki, so go ahead and add it.

Comment: @MoisheKohan For Churchill, it's even deeper than that.   He was in the British leadership in WWI, and was demoted for military failures.  I.e. in WW1 he failed at exactly the sort of thing he succeeded at in WW2.

Comment: @GorttheRobot  great summary, very useful for OP's instructional goal. Should that be in the answer?

Comment: @GorttheRobot: Yes, he did learn from his mistakes.